# Unknown constructor issue

Tags: apex, class, constructor

I have an apex class for which i get error:

uknown constructor

the code:

```
public with sharing class SendDocumentCont{

public String ....

public SendDocumentCont(ApexPages.StandardController c)
```

what is the reason of this happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Unknown constructor" means the types and/or number of parameters are incorrect. All classes get, by default, a zero-argument constructor with the same access level as the class itself (e.g. a public class gets a default public zero-argument constructor). If you write at least one constructor in the class, however, this default zero-argument constructor can no longer be used. You must also write your own zero-argument constructor if you want to have access to it.

This means that, for your class, you cannot write:

```
new SendDocumentCont();
```

Because there is no default zero-argument constructor, nor a zero-argument constructor you've written yourself. You must either provide the correct argument, or write a zero-argument constructor.

Example:

```
ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Account());
SendDocumentCont cont = new SendDocumentCont(controller);
```

If you're getting this error in a Visualforce page, you must make sure you have the correct parameter provided. Controllers may use ApexPages.StandardController, ApexPages.StandardSetController, or a custom controller (a class of your own writing).

To write a zero-argument constructor, just add it to the class:

```
public SendDocumentCont() { 
}
```